# how can i construct the bezier curve if i only have points in x axis?

Tags: math, bezier

how can i construct the bezier curve if i only have points in x axis?can i do this act or need points for x and y axes related to t parameter?
i want constructe a bezier curve(from degree N)in a given interval and known point in that interval(that are random), but i have points only in x axes!!Whether this is feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify the slopes at the end-points. You will need to do this for any bezier curve, The fact that the data points are on the x-axis is irrelevant.